# Append query to validate data

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am using an Access 2007 append query with parameters values, to enable a data entry clerk to  input data into a table.  Please advise how I go about forcing  the data  that is inputted in the text field “new_part_ID” to always be uppercase and to for the numeric field “workorder Qty”  to be a whole number and not text
thank you  very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input ( new_part_ID, [workorder Qty] )
    SELECT [please CAREFULLY enter  work order  part_ID in UPPERCASE] AS Expr1, [please CAREFULLY enter the work order Qty] AS Expr2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the upper case part you can just convert the input on the fly like so

```
INSERT INTO tbl_New_part_ID_input ( new_part_ID, [workorder Qty] )
    SELECT upper([please CAREFULLY enter  work order  part_ID]) AS Expr1, [please CAREFULLY enter the work order Qty] AS Expr2;
```

As for forcing a whole number for the quantity. You could always set the field type to only allow whole numbers which would make the query error. Another option is to apply a rounding function of some sort on the quantity the user enters.

There really isn't a way to show a validation message associated with query inputs directly. If you really must do this I suggest using a form instead of a query and putting validation rules on the field. Alternatively you could apply validation rules on the field directly in the table instead of the query.